# ubuntu dpkg недостаточно места в разделе boot No space left on device

Tags: ubuntu, boot, dpkg

```
Linux enc 4.8.0-54-generic #57~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 24 16:22:28 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

при использовании aptitude возникает следующий вывод

```
 Настраивается пакет linux-image-extra-4.8.0-54-generic (4.8.0-54.57~16.04.1) …
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-54-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-54-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-54-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-54-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.8.0-54-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-54-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-54-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-54-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета linux-image-extra-4.8.0-54-generic (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 зависит от linux-image-extra-4.8.0-54-generic, однако:
  Пакет linux-image-extra-4.8.0-54-generic пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет linux-generic-hwe-16.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 зависит от linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (= 4.8.0.54.25), однако:
  Пакет linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 пок�Отчёты apport не записаны, так как сообщение об ошибке указывает на повторную ошибку от предыдущего отказа.
                                                                 Отчёты apport не записаны, так как сообщение об ошибке указывает на повторную ошибку от предыдущего отказа.
            � не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета linux-generic-hwe-16.04 (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
Настраивается пакет libboost-regex1.58.0:amd64 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) …
Настраивается пакет mkvtoolnix (12.0.0-0~bunkus01) …

При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-54-generic
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Ошибка при выполнении запрошенной операции с пакетом. Попытка восстановить:
Настраивается пакет linux-image-extra-4.8.0-54-generic (4.8.0-54.57~16.04.1) …
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-54-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-54-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-54-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-54-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.8.0-54-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-54-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-54-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
cpio: ошибка записи: Обрыв канала
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 1 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-54-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета linux-image-extra-4.8.0-54-generic (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 зависит от linux-image-extra-4.8.0-54-generic, однако:
  Пакет linux-image-extra-4.8.0-54-generic пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет linux-generic-hwe-16.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 зависит от linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (= 4.8.0.54.25), однако:
  Пакет linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета linux-generic-hwe-16.04 (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
linux-image-extra-4.8.0-54-generic
linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

объем раздела /boot - 500 мБ

однако свободными остались лишь около 14 мБ

вывод ls -R -a для boot:

```
.:

.            config-4.8.0-53-generic      System.map-4.8.0-44-generic

..           config-4.8.0-54-generic      System.map-4.8.0-45-generic

abi-4.8.0-36-generic     grub                 System.map-4.8.0-46-generic

abi-4.8.0-44-generic     initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic  System.map-4.8.0-49-generic

abi-4.8.0-45-generic     initrd.img-4.8.0-44-generic  System.map-4.8.0-52-generic

abi-4.8.0-46-generic     initrd.img-4.8.0-45-generic  System.map-4.8.0-53-generic

abi-4.8.0-49-generic     initrd.img-4.8.0-46-generic  System.map-4.8.0-54-generic

abi-4.8.0-52-generic     initrd.img-4.8.0-49-generic  vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic

abi-4.8.0-53-generic     initrd.img-4.8.0-52-generic  vmlinuz-4.8.0-44-generic

abi-4.8.0-54-generic     initrd.img-4.8.0-53-generic  vmlinuz-4.8.0-45-generic

config-4.8.0-36-generic  initrd.img-4.8.0-54-generic  vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic

config-4.8.0-44-generic  lost+found           vmlinuz-4.8.0-49-generic

config-4.8.0-45-generic  memtest86+.bin           vmlinuz-4.8.0-52-generic

config-4.8.0-46-generic  memtest86+.elf           vmlinuz-4.8.0-53-generic

config-4.8.0-49-generic  memtest86+_multiboot.bin     vmlinuz-4.8.0-54-generic

config-4.8.0-52-generic  System.map-4.8.0-36-generic


./grub:

.  ..  fonts  gfxblacklist.txt  grub.cfg  grubenv  i386-pc  locale  unicode.pf2


./grub/fonts:

.  ..  unicode.pf2


./grub/i386-pc:

.             gcry_tiger.mod        parttool.mod

..            gcry_twofish.mod      password.mod

915resolution.mod     gcry_whirlpool.mod    password_pbkdf2.mod

acpi.mod          gdb.mod           pata.mod

adler32.mod       geli.mod          pbkdf2.mod

affs.mod          gettext.mod       pbkdf2_test.mod

afs.mod           gfxmenu.mod       pcidump.mod

ahci.mod          gfxterm_background.mod    pci.mod

all_video.mod         gfxterm_menu.mod      plan9.mod

aout.mod          gfxterm.mod       play.mod

archelp.mod       gptsync.mod       png.mod

ata.mod           gzio.mod          priority_queue.mod

at_keyboard.mod       halt.mod          probe.mod

backtrace.mod         hashsum.mod       procfs.mod

bfs.mod           hdparm.mod        progress.mod

biosdisk.mod          hello.mod         pxechain.mod

bitmap.mod        help.mod          pxe.mod

bitmap_scale.mod      hexdump.mod       raid5rec.mod

blocklist.mod         hfs.mod           raid6rec.mod

boot.img          hfspluscomp.mod       read.mod

boot.mod          hfsplus.mod       reboot.mod

bsd.mod           http.mod          regexp.mod

btrfs.mod         hwmatch.mod       reiserfs.mod

bufio.mod         iorw.mod          relocator.mod

cat.mod           iso9660.mod       romfs.mod

cbfs.mod          jfs.mod           scsi.mod

cbls.mod          jpeg.mod          search_fs_file.mod

cbmemc.mod        keylayouts.mod        search_fs_uuid.mod

cbtable.mod       keystatus.mod     search_label.mod

cbtime.mod        ldm.mod           search.mod

chain.mod         legacycfg.mod     sendkey.mod

cmdline_cat_test.mod  legacy_password_test.mod  serial.mod

cmosdump.mod          linux16.mod       setjmp.mod

cmostest.mod          linux.mod         setjmp_test.mod

cmp.mod           loadenv.mod       setpci.mod

command.lst       loopback.mod      sfs.mod

configfile.mod        lsacpi.mod        signature_test.mod

core.img          lsapm.mod         sleep.mod

cpio_be.mod       lsmmap.mod        sleep_test.mod

cpio.mod          ls.mod            spkmodem.mod

cpuid.mod         lspci.mod         squash4.mod

crc64.mod         luks.mod          syslinuxcfg.mod

cryptodisk.mod        lvm.mod           tar.mod

crypto.lst        lzopio.mod        terminal.lst

crypto.mod        macbless.mod      terminal.mod

cs5536.mod        macho.mod         terminfo.mod

datehook.mod          mda_text.mod      test_blockarg.mod

date.mod          mdraid09_be.mod       testload.mod

datetime.mod          mdraid09.mod      test.mod

diskfilter.mod        mdraid1x.mod      testspeed.mod

disk.mod          memdisk.mod       tftp.mod

div_test.mod          memrw.mod         tga.mod

dm_nv.mod         minicmd.mod       time.mod

drivemap.mod          minix2_be.mod     trig.mod

echo.mod          minix2.mod        tr.mod

efiemu32.o        minix3_be.mod     truecrypt.mod

efiemu64.o        minix3.mod        true.mod

efiemu.mod        minix_be.mod      udf.mod

ehci.mod          minix.mod         ufs1_be.mod

elf.mod           mmap.mod          ufs1.mod

eval.mod          moddep.lst        ufs2.mod

exfat.mod         modinfo.sh        uhci.mod

exfctest.mod          morse.mod         usb_keyboard.mod

ext2.mod          mpi.mod           usb.mod

extcmd.mod        msdospart.mod     usbms.mod

fat.mod           multiboot2.mod        usbserial_common.mod

file.mod          multiboot.mod     usbserial_ftdi.mod

font.mod          nativedisk.mod        usbserial_pl2303.mod

freedos.mod       net.mod           usbserial_usbdebug.mod

fshelp.mod        newc.mod          usbtest.mod

fs.lst            nilfs2.mod        vbe.mod

functional_test.mod   normal.mod        verify.mod

gcry_arcfour.mod      ntfscomp.mod      vga.mod

gcry_blowfish.mod     ntfs.mod          vga_text.mod

gcry_camellia.mod     ntldr.mod         video_bochs.mod

gcry_cast5.mod        odc.mod           video_cirrus.mod

gcry_crc.mod          offsetio.mod      video_colors.mod

gcry_des.mod          ohci.mod          video_fb.mod

gcry_dsa.mod          part_acorn.mod        videoinfo.mod

gcry_idea.mod         part_amiga.mod        video.lst

gcry_md4.mod          part_apple.mod        video.mod

gcry_md5.mod          part_bsd.mod      videotest_checksum.mod

gcry_rfc2268.mod      part_dfly.mod     videotest.mod

gcry_rijndael.mod     part_dvh.mod      xfs.mod

gcry_rmd160.mod       part_gpt.mod      xnu.mod

gcry_rsa.mod          partmap.lst       xnu_uuid.mod

gcry_seed.mod         part_msdos.mod        xnu_uuid_test.mod

gcry_serpent.mod      part_plan.mod     xzio.mod

gcry_sha1.mod         part_sun.mod      zfscrypt.mod

gcry_sha256.mod       part_sunpc.mod        zfsinfo.mod

gcry_sha512.mod       parttool.lst      zfs.mod


./grub/locale:

.  ..  en_AU.mo  en_CA.mo  en_GB.mo  en@quot.mo  ru.mo


./lost+found:

.  ..
```

Вопрос в следующем: как я могу освободить необходимое количество занимаемого пространства?

Что можно удалить в ручную?

Либо, как настроить автоудаление неиспользуемых файлов?

Comment: sudo apt-get autoremove для начала

Comment: Прокомментирую остальные ответы: у вас на машине набралось порядочное количество версий ядра linux, для каждого из которых создается своя загрузочная конфигурация. Раздела /boot в определенный момент перестало хватать, лечится это, как указано в ответах, удалением старых и ненужных версий ядра. В идеале у вас на машине должны оставаться только две версии ядра, чтобы в случае каких-либо проблем с новым можно было запуститься с предыдущего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можете удалить старые версии программы *linux*:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.8.0-{36,44,45,46,49,52}-generic
```

---

если эта команда тоже завершится ошибкой с жалобой на нехватку места, можно вручную удалить файлы пары версий:

```
$ sudo rm /boot/{vmlinuz,initrd.img,abi}-4.8.0-{36,44}-generic
```

и вновь её выполнить.

Comment: спасибо, все завершилось без ошибок

Answer (score 1):

Предложу такой скрипт, найденный когда-то на просторах интернета. Пользуюсь давно, но, возможно, кто-то посчитает его из серии "вредные советы".

`$ cat ubucleaner.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')
CURKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')
LINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"
METALINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"
OLDKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $LINUXPKG |grep -vE $METALINUXPKG|grep -v $CURKERNEL)
YELLOW="\033[1;33m"
RED="\033[0;31m"
ENDCOLOR="\033[0m"

if [ $USER != root ]; then
      echo -e $RED"Ошибка: вы должны быть root"
      echo -e $YELLOW"Выходим..."$ENDCOLOR
  exit 0
fi

echo -e $YELLOW"Очищаем кэш apt..."$ENDCOLOR
aptitude clean

# echo -e $YELLOW"Удаляем старые конфиги..."$ENDCOLOR
# sudo aptitude purge $OLDCONF # (!) использовать осознанно

echo -e $YELLOW"Удаляем старые ядра..."$ENDCOLOR
sudo aptitude purge $OLDKERNELS

echo -e $YELLOW"Опустошаем все корзины..."$ENDCOLOR
rm -rf /home/*/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
rm -rf /root/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null

echo -e $YELLOW"Скрипт закончил работу!"$ENDCOLOR
```

Comment: `sudo aptitude purge $OLDCONF` — однозначно вредный совет. удалять конфигурационные файлы (временно) удалённых пакетов пользователь должен сознательно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, согласен.

Comment: спасибо, скрипт сохраню