# Установка letsncrypt на сервер: No space left on device

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, letsencrypt

Сервер -> Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Apache2.

При установке certbot или letsencrypt возвращает такую ошибку:

```
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic (4.4.0-128.154) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-128-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-128-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-128-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-128-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-128-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-128-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-128-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-128-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_AUo8te/lib/modules/4.4.0-128-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_AUo8te/lib/modules/4.4.0-128-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory



  gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-128-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1



Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Как я понял, ругается на память, но свободно 15 гиг.

Может, нужно расширить для директории память?

### Результат : df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            351M     0  351M   0% /dev
tmpfs            74M  8.0M   66M  11% /run
/dev/xvda3       24G   15G  7.3G  68% /
tmpfs           368M     0  368M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           368M     0  368M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1      190M  179M     0 100% /boot
tmpfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/lxcfs/controllers
tmpfs            74M     0   74M   0% /run/user/0
```

### Результат : ls -lh /boot

```
total 171M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M Dec 11  2017 abi-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M Jan  7  2018 abi-4.4.0-108-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M Apr  2 20:51 abi-4.4.0-119-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M Aug 27 17:10 abi-4.4.0-135-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M Jun 24  2016 abi-4.4.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 190K Dec 11  2017 config-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 190K Jan  7  2018 config-4.4.0-108-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 190K Apr  2 20:51 config-4.4.0-119-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 190K Aug 27 17:10 config-4.4.0-135-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 189K Jun 24  2016 config-4.4.0-28-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 1.0K Sep 11 17:12 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  34M Dec 18  2017 initrd.img-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  34M Jan 10  2018 initrd.img-4.4.0-108-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7.6M Sep 11 17:12 initrd.img-4.4.0-109-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7.6M Sep 11 17:08 initrd.img-4.4.0-121-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  34M Dec 18  2017 initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
drwx------ 2 root root  12K Jul  2  2016 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.0K Apr  2 20:51 retpoline-4.4.0-119-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.1K Aug 27 17:10 retpoline-4.4.0-135-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 3.0M Dec 11  2017 System.map-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 3.0M Jan  7  2018 System.map-4.4.0-108-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 3.0M Apr  2 20:51 System.map-4.4.0-119-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 3.0M Aug 27 17:10 System.map-4.4.0-135-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 3.0M Jun 24  2016 System.map-4.4.0-28-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 6.6M Dec 11  2017 vmlinuz-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 6.6M Jan  7  2018 vmlinuz-4.4.0-108-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 6.6M Apr  2 20:51 vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 6.6M Aug 27 17:10 vmlinuz-4.4.0-135-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 6.5M Jun 24  2016 vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
```

Результат sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/(.*)-([^0-9]+)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* ([^ ]*).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | head -n -1)

```
18 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 974 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 229859 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic (4.4.0-112.135) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-112-generic: No such 
file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-112- 
generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-112- 
generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
depmod: WARNING: could not open 
/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_utpBfF/lib/modules/4.4.0-112-generic/modules.order: No 
such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open 
/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_utpBfF/lib/modules/4.4.0-112-generic/modules.builtin: 
No such file or directory
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f не помогает , такая же ошибка ... Вообще что не поставить - возвращает подобное ((

Comment: Читайте выше по тексту ошибки, что именно сломалось. В приведённом куске нет ничего информативного. Ну а certbot естественно ни при чём

Comment: @andreymal Исправил пост с тем что выводит выше .

Comment: Скорее всего у вас кончилось место на разделе /boot, попробуйте sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: @andreymal не помогает , отладка такая же... Уже много чего пробовал . Может можно как-то расширить boot ?

Comment: Что ж, придётся удалять файлы вручную. Попробуйте `sudo mv /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic ~ && sudo mv /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic ~` и затем `sudo apt-get install --force-reinstall=true linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic` (если сделаете это, не перезагружайте компьютер до починки, а то после ручного удаления без починки система рискует не загрузиться обратно) (я предлагаю mv вместо rm, чтобы можно было вернуть на место на всякий случай)

Comment: Если эти команды сработают успешно, то потом ещё раз `sudo apt-get autoremove` и наверно можно попробовать перезагрузиться

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо , сейчас попробую .

Comment: (хотя я тут подумал, что возможно install не стоило делать, а сразу autoremove после ручного удаления файлов)

Comment: @andreymal Я пока все равно не пробовал , так как на серваке развернут рабочий проект . Буду править ночью , сделаю сначала без install

Comment: В общем суть в том, чтобы освободить на /boot хоть немного места, а потом с помощью autoremove доосвободить оставшееся. На случай, если autoremove ничего не удалит, попробуйте удалить вручную: `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic` // А вообще в убунте для удаления старых ядер есть специальная команда: `sudo apt-get install byobu` и затем `sudo purge-old-kernels` (но это уже после того как починится)

Comment: А вообще такой вопрос, оказывается, уже задавали: [ubuntu dpkg недостаточно места в разделе boot No space left on device](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677092) — там советуют примерно то же самое

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо огромное за помощь , думаю все получится . Отмечу после того как сделаю .

Comment: @andreymal к сожалению никакой из вариантов не помогает , возвращает такую же ошибку . То что вопрос отмечен как дубликат - переходил по нему , пробовал - ситуация та же ... ((

Comment: Ну это уже совсем странно, тогда покажите `df -h` и `ls -lh /boot`

Comment: @andreymal Добавил к описанию проблемы .

Comment: Ну, удалите ещё что-то? 104 и 108 как минимум

Comment: @andreymal вообще ничего не хочет удалять , только сейчас обратил внимание после комманды sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | head -n -1)  Результат добавил в описании